# How to create a pagination and sorting using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, pagination

I need to create a pagination using jquery which displays 5 results per page. Also I must allow the user to sort the results by price.

I created the pagination and it works fine. The bug is in the sorting function. When the user sorts the results it just sorts the results available in the specific page and not the total results. [Here is the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ez50oqsc/)
The below is the function to sort the price.

```
var ascending = false;
$('.sortc').on('click', '.sortp', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sorted = $('ul .price_indiv').sort(function (a, b) {
        return (ascending == (convertToNumber($(a).find('.final_price').html()) < convertToNumber($(b).find('.final_price').html()))) ? 1 : -1;
    });
    ascending = ascending ? false : true;

    $('.price').html(sorted);
});
var convertToNumber = function (value) {
    return parseFloat(value.replace('$', ''));
}
```

Can someone help me to fix this bug? NOTE: Without a plugin

Comment: try datatable: https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Dude... I saw your `fiddle`.. its working properly..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood how the Pager works.You may need to re-evaluate how this script works. It displays the proper items and simply hides the rest of the list items using `display:none;`

**Before Sort**

---

[image: Before Sort]!

---

**After Sort**

---

[image: After Sort]!

---

So as DarkHorse said sorting is working perfectly. All you need to do is just may be reapply sorting function to get it work